# How can I troubleshoot why the Node.JS libuv threadpool gets stuck?

Tags: node.js

I have a Node.JS app with many async operations that gets stuck in the threadpool. The symptom is that simple async fs operations do not complete. For example,

```
fs.open("/etc/hostname", function (err, fd) { console.log("Opened hostname") })
```

never prints anything. Or a `fs.readFile` never calls the callback, yet `fs.readFileSync` of the same file works perfectly.

If I increase the threadpool using the `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE` environment variable the identical code works as expected (I have not tested for how long).
I'm assuming that there are some operations that are stuck in the threadpool and that do not complete. How can I find out (a) whether that's truly the case, and (b) which operations they are?

NB: using node 14 or 18 on rpi.

Comment: First thing to check is if you have any infinite loop in your code. One quick way to do that is run your code in a debugger (see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) and then after a few seconds pause the app and see what piece of code is currently being executed. If there is an infinite loop it should be stock in the loop.

Comment: The app continues to run. It uses express and I can keep making requests to endpoints that don't use async file operations. Also, it runs stuff on timers and those fire and execute, I can see that in the log file.